# kotlin generic functions returns ClassCastException

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, retrofit

lets say that I have a generic function like this

```
@GET("leagues/")
suspend fun <T> getLeagueStandings(
    @Query("user")
    user: String = Shared.USER,
    @Query("token")
    token: String = Shared.TOKEN,
    @Query("t")
    t: String = "standings",
    @Query("season_id")
    seasonId: Int = 12880
): Response<T>
```

Then I have two models like this

model 1

```
data class Standings(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val `data`: Data?,
    @SerializedName("meta")
    val meta: Meta?
) {
    data class Data(
        @SerializedName("has_groups")
        val hasGroups: Int?,
        @SerializedName("league_id")
        val leagueId: String?,
        @SerializedName("number_standings")
        val numberStandings: Int?,
        @SerializedName("season_id")
        val seasonId: String?,
        @SerializedName("standings")
        val standings: List<Standing?>?
    ) {
        data class Standing(
            @SerializedName("away")
            val away: Away?,
            @SerializedName("group")
            val group: String?,
            @SerializedName("group_name")
            val groupName: String?,
            @SerializedName("home")
            val home: Home?,
            @SerializedName("overall")
            val overall: Overall?,
            @SerializedName("points")
            val points: Int?,
            @SerializedName("recent_form")
            val recentForm: String?,
            @SerializedName("result")
            val result: String?,
            @SerializedName("status")
            val status: String?,
            @SerializedName("team_id")
            val teamId: String?,
            @SerializedName("team_name")
            val teamName: String?,
            @SerializedName("total")
            val total: Int?
        ) {
            data class Away(
                @SerializedName("draw")
                val draw: Int?,
                @SerializedName("games_played")
                val gamesPlayed: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_against")
                val goalsAgainst: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_diff")
                val goalsDiff: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_scored")
                val goalsScored: Int?,
                @SerializedName("lost")
                val lost: Int?,
                @SerializedName("points")
                val points: Int?,
                @SerializedName("position")
                val position: Int?,
                @SerializedName("won")
                val won: Int?
            )

            data class Home(
                @SerializedName("draw")
                val draw: Int?,
                @SerializedName("games_played")
                val gamesPlayed: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_against")
                val goalsAgainst: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_diff")
                val goalsDiff: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_scored")
                val goalsScored: Int?,
                @SerializedName("lost")
                val lost: Int?,
                @SerializedName("points")
                val points: Int?,
                @SerializedName("position")
                val position: Int?,
                @SerializedName("won")
                val won: Int?
            )

            data class Overall(
                @SerializedName("draw")
                val draw: Int?,
                @SerializedName("games_played")
                val gamesPlayed: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_against")
                val goalsAgainst: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_diff")
                val goalsDiff: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_scored")
                val goalsScored: Int?,
                @SerializedName("lost")
                val lost: Int?,
                @SerializedName("points")
                val points: Int?,
                @SerializedName("position")
                val position: Int?,
                @SerializedName("won")
                val won: Int?
            )
        }
    }

    data class Meta(
        @SerializedName("count")
        val count: Int?,
        @SerializedName("msg")
        val msg: Any?,
        @SerializedName("page")
        val page: Int?,
        @SerializedName("pages")
        val pages: Int?,
        @SerializedName("plan")
        val plan: String?,
        @SerializedName("requests_left")
        val requestsLeft: Int?,
        @SerializedName("total")
        val total: Int?,
        @SerializedName("user")
        val user: String?
    )
}
```

model 2

```
data class Standings2(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val `data`: Data?,
    @SerializedName("meta")
    val meta: Meta?
) {
    data class Data(
        @SerializedName("has_groups")
        val hasGroups: Int?,
        @SerializedName("league_id")
        val leagueId: String?,
        @SerializedName("number_standings")
        val numberStandings: Int?,
        @SerializedName("season_id")
        val seasonId: String?,
        @SerializedName("standings")
        val standings: List<List<Standing?>?>? //difference from model 1
    ) {
        data class Standing(
            @SerializedName("away")
            val away: Away?,
            @SerializedName("group")
            val group: String?,
            @SerializedName("group_name")
            val groupName: String?,
            @SerializedName("home")
            val home: Home?,
            @SerializedName("overall")
            val overall: Overall?,
            @SerializedName("points")
            val points: Int?,
            @SerializedName("recent_form")
            val recentForm: String?,
            @SerializedName("result")
            val result: String?,
            @SerializedName("status")
            val status: String?,
            @SerializedName("team_id")
            val teamId: String?,
            @SerializedName("team_name")
            val teamName: String?,
            @SerializedName("total")
            val total: Int?
        ) {
            data class Away(
                @SerializedName("draw")
                val draw: Int?,
                @SerializedName("games_played")
                val gamesPlayed: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_against")
                val goalsAgainst: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_diff")
                val goalsDiff: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_scored")
                val goalsScored: Int?,
                @SerializedName("lost")
                val lost: Int?,
                @SerializedName("points")
                val points: Int?,
                @SerializedName("position")
                val position: Int?,
                @SerializedName("won")
                val won: Int?
            )

            data class Home(
                @SerializedName("draw")
                val draw: Int?,
                @SerializedName("games_played")
                val gamesPlayed: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_against")
                val goalsAgainst: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_diff")
                val goalsDiff: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_scored")
                val goalsScored: Int?,
                @SerializedName("lost")
                val lost: Int?,
                @SerializedName("points")
                val points: Int?,
                @SerializedName("position")
                val position: Int?,
                @SerializedName("won")
                val won: Int?
            )

            data class Overall(
                @SerializedName("draw")
                val draw: Int?,
                @SerializedName("games_played")
                val gamesPlayed: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_against")
                val goalsAgainst: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_diff")
                val goalsDiff: Int?,
                @SerializedName("goals_scored")
                val goalsScored: Int?,
                @SerializedName("lost")
                val lost: Int?,
                @SerializedName("points")
                val points: Int?,
                @SerializedName("position")
                val position: Int?,
                @SerializedName("won")
                val won: Int?
            )
        }
    }

    data class Meta(
        @SerializedName("count")
        val count: Int?,
        @SerializedName("msg")
        val msg: Any?,
        @SerializedName("page")
        val page: Int?,
        @SerializedName("pages")
        val pages: Int?,
        @SerializedName("plan")
        val plan: String?,
        @SerializedName("requests_left")
        val requestsLeft: Int?,
        @SerializedName("total")
        val total: Int?,
        @SerializedName("user")
        val user: String?
    )
}
```

since getLeagueStandings() is a generic function, it's supposed that I can get instances of `Standings` and `Standings2` just by calling them like this

```
val response: Response<Standings> = api.getLeagueStandings(seasonId = 1)
```

but actually, this call returns `ClassCastException`.
so what did I miss or what is Wrong

Edit:- here's the error message I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to retrofit2.Response
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? The endpoint `leagues/` on your API returns a JSON in a specific format. So it's either `Standings` or `Standings2` or something else. It can't be both. If you want the response in a specific format you need:

 - to provide a class matching the JSON response
 - then map the response from that class to either `Standings` or `Standings2`.

Generic types are not auto-magically mapping something into something else.

Comment: @Eselfar thank you for your response, I have added the error message. As you said the API returns JSON either `Standings` or `Standings2` but I mentioned `Standings` as an example for simplicity since they are the same idea and `Standings` match the JSON response